# How to set minTime in pm and maxTime in am for a Timepicker input?

Tags: jquery, time, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I need to set `minTime` in pm format and `maxTime` in am (i.e)
`minTime` is today's noon and `maxTime` is tomorrow's morning. 
below is the snippet i used.

```
$('.fromtime').timepicker({
    stepMinute: 5,
    'minTime': '5:00 pm',
    'maxTime': '2:15 am'
});
```